# Ionic Images not showing on first page load

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3

im having an issue with images located on `src/assets/images`
Here's my ionic info output:

```
$ ionic info

cli packages: (C:\Users\Win 7\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v8.11.1
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : Windows 7

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\Win 7\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

When the page loads the first time images dont load, then i exit the page and re-enter to it again and the images are here x)

I used `<ion-img src="..."></ion-img>` tag

Comment: You are directly passing image path to src?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are directly passing the image path from assets as the source of , then use below code will fix the **x** sign issue:

```
<img src="assets/images/logo.png">
```

Comment: Then give more description of your problem

Comment: Wait, img src isnt same as ion-img src ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can insert image in your Ionic application.

```
<img src="assets/icon/myImage.png" class="image-responsive">
```